# TextSize for different device with different size?

Tags: android, textview, text-size

How can support text size for different devices with different screen size ? I have try to provide different dimension xml for different screen but it's not working efficiently.

values
values-large
values-small
values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp
values-sw800dp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this library, it may help you. [CommonTextSize](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

In your layout add like this to mention size   `android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"`

Comment: @BincyBaby: Credits goes to that Developer, for such a wonderful solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is accurate when you have values values-large values-small values-sw600dp values-sw720dp values-sw800dp etc folders. However i think you are missing to change textsize dimensions in `values/dimens.xml values-large/dimens.xml  values-small/dimens.xml  values-sw600dp/dimens.xml  values-sw720dp/dimens.xml  values-sw800dp/dimens.xml`.

For example you have used something like below `dimens.xml` in your values/dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="text_size">18sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

In other values folder you need to change values for your text size.Also use `sp` for textsize not px or dp.

Please note that `values values-large values-small` are depricated after honeycomb.

You can also use the library as suggested in the other answer.However if you don't want to use an extra library then try this.

**Programmatically**

Here's a method which converts size of `dp` to the size according to screen size.

```
public float convertFromDp(int input) {
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
return ((input - 0.5f) / scale);
}
```

Now simply give the value to the textsize programically.

```
tvTextView1.setTextSize(convertFromDp(24));
```

Comment: I have provide size in dp in all xml file.

Comment: Please try the programmatic way solution too if you are dealing with dynamic texts. You can also try the library mentioned in the other answer.